# Erro "illegal start of expression"

Tags: java

Na minha `main` eu estou chamando o método `stats`:

```
user.stats(ctr);
```

O método `stats` em si:

```
public void stats (int num)
{
    int i;
    float total=0, perc;
    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        total = total + sensors[i].statistics.getTotalConsumption(sensors[i].statistics.data[]);
    }
}
```

A classe `users`:

```
public class Users implements IUsers{
protected int id;
protected String name;
protected int age;
protected String email;
protected String phone;
protected Sensors sensors[] = new Sensors[10];
float cost;
float goal;

public Users()
{

}

public void stats (int num)
{
    int i;
    float total=0, perc;
    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        total = total + sensors[i].statistics.getTotalConsumption(sensors[i].statistics.data[]);
    }
}
}
```

O `main`:

```
public class UserTest 
{ 
public static void main ( String args[] )
{
    int id, rg, cpf, cnpj, num, age, ctr=0;
    String name, name2, description, description2, email, phone, c, g, sex;
    Sensors sensors[];
    float cost, goal;


    Users user = new Users();
    while (ctr!=num)
    {
        user.sensors[ctr] = new Sensors();
        name2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nome do aparelho ligado ao sensor");
        description = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Localização do aparelho");
        user.sensors[ctr].setNome(name2);
        user.sensors[ctr].setDescription(description);
        ctr++;
    }
    /*exibir estatísticas*/
    user.stats(ctr);
}
}
```

Mas tanto na chamada do método quanto na atribuição da variável total, está dando o erro `illegal start of expression`. Se alguém puder ajudar fico grato.

Comment: Onde e como é feita a declaração de `sensors`?

Comment: Veja se está a usar as palavras `public` ou  `private` dentro de um método ou se está a declarar um método dentro de outro.

Comment: protected Sensors sensors[] = new Sensors[10];

Comment: Essa declaração está ser feita onde? Verifique o meu segundo comentário.

Comment: essa declaração está dentro da classe Users, assim como o método stats

Comment: poste sua main e a classe que contém o método stats para que seja melhor identificar o que está acontecendo.

Comment: pronto, atualizei

Comment: foi apenas uma falha na hora de copiar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro encontra-se no teu método `stats`

```
public void stats (int num)
{
    int i;
    float total=0, perc;
    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        total = total + sensors[i].statistics.getTotalConsumption(sensors[i].statistics.data[]);  //<--- não estás a indexar o array data[faltaAquiUmIndice]. Ou data não é um array
    }
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo! valeu, cara.

Comment: Ainda bem que pude ajudar!